# What if i change the SQLite DB name?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have changed the data format for my app, so all previously stored data in SQLite DB with DB_NAME_1 is not useful. I want to delete previous data and store new data with a new DB_NAME_2.

I used SQLiteOpenHelper class for creating DB in my code and ContentProvider class to access tables.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_BOOK + " ("+TABLE_BOOK_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + TABLE_BOOK_TOPIC + " integer, "   + TABLE_BOOK_TIME+" long, " 
            + TABLE_BOOK_PAGE_DATA+" text, " +  TABLE_BOOK_PAGE_SCORE + " integer);");  
}
```

1. How can i do that?
2. If i simply change the DB_NAME_1 to DB_NAME_2, it will create a new file with DB_NAME_2. How can i delete the previous file with DB_NAME_1.

Comment: Delete the app completely from your test device/emulator should do it.

Comment: Maybe I don't get you right... rename the db file to a new name. Then refer it in code with the new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i do that?

Supply the new name to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor and a new database file will be created if it doesn't already exist.

> If i simply change the DB_NAME_1 to DB_NAME_2, it will create a new file with DB_NAME_2. How can i delete the previous file with DB_NAME_

Call [`deleteDatabase(DB_NAME_1)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)) on a `Context`.